# Firewall rule to allow file sharing over VPN on Windows 8

Tags: vpn, firewall, windows-8

I have setup my Windows 8 as a VPN server and forwarded the port. It works fine except for file sharing. When I disable the firewall on the VPN server I can access the shared folders using the IP address and hostname but once I re-enable the firewall it's blocked again. Does anyone know which rule should be allowed and whether it would be under inbound or outbound rules (I'm guessing inbound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to open port 445 on the firewall.

Comment: Ok it worked, created a new rule, added port 445 (inbound tcp) on domain, public and private networks and voila. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to open the following ports inbound

TCP Ports 135, 139, 445

UDP Port 137

Comment: 445 is all that is necessary in this case.